# Compare dates depending on format

Tags: java, date, gwt, comparison

I've built a custom data grid and I've added some filters. 
One filter I have is a date filter, for cells that display dates.
My problem is that the cell might display

```
Displayed date value : 21/01/2014 , Actual date object value : 21-01-2014 16:32:0000
```

Of course the user doesn't know about the hour part, so when he/she provides a filter value of the same day, month and year expects to see the matched elements. This of course will not happen since the comparator, compares date objects that have different hour values.

What I want to ask is, is there a preferred way to compare two date objects depending on the display format? I can implement this logic, I was just curious if some implementation already existed.

Update

I have two date objects :

1. 21-01-2014 16:32:0000
2. 21-01-2014 00:00:0000

and a display format : "dd/MM/yyyy"

Is there a preferred way of combining these two dates depending on the format?
This means only comparing the parts of the date that are included in the format.
In the case above compare only day(dd), month(MM), year(yyyy).

I'm repeating I can implement something simple myself, I'm just curious if anyone else has encountered this before and has found a generic solution.

Comment: I could not understand your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution on the client side (where the Java code is compiled to Javascript by the GWT compiler), [Krzysztof's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30526998/181497) solution will not work. GWT [does not support `Calendar` and related classes](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) on the client side. `SimpleDateFormat` is not supported either - [`DateTimeFormat` has to be used instead](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsFormatting.html#datetimeformat).

There is however a useful utility class available in GWT: [`CalendarUtil`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html). It has a `isSameDate(java.util.Date date0, java.util.Date date1)` method which does exactly what you want:

> Check if two dates represent the same date of the same year, even if they have different times.

BTW, it also has a `resetTime(java.util.Date date)` method which could be useful in your use case:

> Resets the date to have no time modifiers.

Comment: I'm changing the accepted answer to this. All the previous answers were already known to me (that doesn't reduces the value of those answers of course, it's just that I wanted something a little less common).

Comment: The question was about java, not GWT. Sure, you can use a library for everything, but using some library just because it has one trivial method is ridicolous.

Comment: Why the downvote? Are you sure you understand the relationship between Java and GWT? Please don't downvote (whoever you are) blindly if you don't. I inferred that the question is about GWT based on the tag the OP used. Plus the "custom data grid" part. I agree that it should be more clearly stated in the question, but it seems this is the correct conclusion, as OP gladly used the class bundled with GWT. I, of course, agree that one should not include a huge library for just one simple utility method, and OP probably agrees too, but he's already using GWT.

Comment: The two other answers using `Calendar` and `LocalDate` simply *will not work* (they won't compile). I agree that they are the "correct"/preferred way in "pure" Java. Unfortunately, since those classes are not supported on the client-side by GWT (as OP stated, he's trying to write a filter for his "custom data grid" - so we are working on the client-side), I proposed a different approach, using an utility class GWT provides exactly for working around those missing classes.

Answer (score 1):

Before comparing modify the `date` in this fashion:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    date = gc.getTime();
```

It will trim it to the same day value, so you can compare the two dates if it they are the same, but since you have trimmed them to day value, those dates will return true when compared regardless of the previous hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds value.

Or you can do:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date date1 = ...;

    Date date2 = ...;

    if (sdf.format(date1).equals(sdf.format(date2))) {
        // dates are equal in the day value
    }
```

Comment: Yes this I thinking too, but I was curious if something better exists. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LocalDate` for any date/time handling in Java. Read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547741/what-are-the-differences-between-joda-localdate-and-java-utils-date)** post for why it's advantageous to use `LocalDate` over other older options.

Having said that, all you need to do to compare your `Date`(s) in the format you requested (dd/MM/yyyy) is this:

Let `date1` and `date2` be the `Date` objects that have your input dates.

```
LocalDate lD1 = new LocalDate(date1);
LocalDate lD2 = new LocalDate(date2);

String comparisonFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

boolean result = lD1.toString(comparisonFormat).equals(lD2.toString(comparisonFormat));
```

You could've done this in a one-liner if that's your thing but I think it's more readable this way.